# My SQL with Python: Select the row with the highest value and change the value there

Tags: python, mysql, groupwise-maximum

I have already searched for several solutions here and tried to get a working code. Everything works except for the where query.

In the where query I search for the highest value (numeric). However, this does not really work...
Here is my code and the structure of the MySQL database.

Thanks!

```
import pymysql
conn = pymysql.connect(host='localhost', unix_socket='', user='root', passwd='pw', db='database')
cur = conn.cursor()
cur.execute("SELECT * FROM dose")
for r in cur:
    curr = conn.cursor()
    sql = """UPDATE dose 
    SET status = "printed" 
    WHERE id = SELECT GREATEST (status) FROM dose (status);"""
    # print(sql)
    try:
       # Execute the SQL command
       curr.execute(sql)
       # Commit your changes in the database
       conn.commit()
    except:
       # Rollback in case there is any error
       conn.rollback()
    curr.close()

cur.close()
conn.close()
```

[My SQL Database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8cC4w.png)

Comment: Your question is not clear.  Please add sample data here.

Comment: Is the status column a number or a string?

Comment: I suggest you run the query in your MySQL terminal and see if it works there. If status is a number then SET status =“printed” seems unlikely to work. Also you seems to have too many quotes around your sql statement.

Comment: Hello, I am running the script in Jupyter Notebook. If I run the script without the WHERE statement, it works. Of course, this changes all the values in the rows. 

In My SQL the data type is a VARCHAR. I hope this helps, I am just starting to learn mysql and python.

Comment: Is the output of `SELECT GREATEST (status) FROM dose (status);` to your liking?

Comment: (@DS_London `too many quotes` Python triple quotes: allows string literals to contain newlines. Recommended for [doc strings](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0257/#what-is-a-docstring), even single-line.)

Comment: Your _cur.execute("SELECT * FROM dose")_ and the _for r in cur:_ don´t make any sense and you don´t use them, so you are executing the same **update** query as many times as rows in the **dose** table

Answer (score 0):

You have a lot of things wrong in your code.

1. You don´t use the results of your first `select` query, and the only thing that you do is iterate over the results to execute an `UPDATE`
2. Your update query is wrong

You should change it to:

```
import pymysql
conn = pymysql.connect(host='localhost', unix_socket='', user='root', passwd='pw', db='database')
curr = conn.cursor()
sql = """UPDATE dose 
    SET status = 'printed' 
    WHERE id = (SELECT max(status) FROM dose) """
try:
   # Execute the SQL command
   curr.execute(sql)
   # Commit your changes in the database
   conn.commit()
except:
   # Rollback in case there is any error
   conn.rollback()
curr.close()

conn.close()
```